# turning off validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have the following in my model:

```
  validates   :name, :if => :should_validate_name?,
              :presence => {:message => "Enter your name"},  
              :length => { :maximum => 50 },
              :allow_blank => true


   def should_validate_name?
 validating_name || new_record? 
end
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
 def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      @user.validating_name = false
      if @user.save
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
 end
```

I don't want to validate for the presence of a name at this point and wish to turn it off.

I thought the code above would work but it doesn't. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the `create` action, creating a new record. So `new_record?` will be true, even if `validating_name` isn't.

Comment: Is there a way I can turn off validation then?

Comment: Yes, make the `:if` method return `false`. Under what circumstances _do_ you want to skip validation?

Comment: We have a form that we want to capture just the email and not the name. Under some circumstances we let users register without a name and under some circumstances we require the name. You answer was spot on and really cleared up this problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer.